# Get layout from view

Tags: android

I am inflating interface from XML using

```
View add_phone = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.phone_info, null);
```

Now how can i access RelativeLayout from add_phone view? is there any methos like `getChildCount()` ?

Comment: Please add your layout (phone_info.xml) in order to be able to help you :)

Comment: i didnt get what are u saying.

Comment: Add your layout in order to be able to tell you exactly how to access it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

yes , getChildCount(), works on a ViewGroup like LinearLayout, RelativeLayout etc..

```
ViewGroup add_phone = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.phone_info, null);
int childCount = add_phone.getChildCount();
```

you must make sure the inflated layout has viewGroup as parent view, otherwise you will get class cast exception. viewGroup can be anything like LinearLayout, RelativeLayout etc..

Comment: can i use same method on add_phone object?

Comment: only if it's a ViewGroup or subclass of ViewGroup.

Answer (score 5):

You can find child views of a view through

```
View.findViewById(int id)
```

In your case, that translates to

```
RelativeLayout child = (RelativeLayout)add_phone.findViewById(R.layout.phone_info)
```

As long as you have unique id's for the child elements in add_phone, this should return the correct element.